# How to fix access to resources using spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, resources

I just copied login/register form with spring security from web and i have huge problems. I want make all resources PUBLIC for all, because after 5 hours i totally don't know what is f****** going on with this spring security.

**Ok here is my configure method 1:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
...
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // URLs matching for access rights
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/DBDesign").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // form login
            .csrf().disable().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .successHandler(sucessHandler)
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            // logout
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
}
```

**configuration method 2:**

```
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/common/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }
}
```

**configuration method 3:**

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**", "/static/**", "/templates/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/webjars/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/templates/");
    }
}
```

I am 100% sure that one of these methods is responsible for managing the directories that are to be available before logging in and which are not.
**Guys please can someone explain how exactly this work?**
Look this is my temporary file structure:

[image]

**green --- i have access**

**red --- i dont have access**

I can copy and paste path to "green" files and see what is inside, but if i am trying to do the same thing for red files... error 404. How is this possible? Only those 2x dont have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resourcehandler `/static/**` points to `classpath:/static/`

So the security-filter should ignore requests to `/sidebar/**`, ....

```java
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/sidebar/**","/diagramER/**", .....);
    }
```

Then you can use in your pages something like

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ....
    <script src="/sidebar/js/main.js" ></script>
    <script src="/diagramER/DBDesign.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sidebar/common/style.css">
</head>
```